# Unauthorized notification requested when invoking notifications/all/read in Trello API

Tags: api, trello

I've been doing some tinkering with the trello API and found myself getting stuck with the notifications part of it. In particular, the PUT requests and POST that are about marking notifications read or unread. I have no idea what direction to go in as it's really straightforward,

Javascript request with a post method to https://api.trello.com/1/notifications/all/read?key[mykey]&token=[userstoken]

And yes, I've made sure I have a read write token. Error I'm getting is as follows

key=[mykey]&
token=[usertoken]HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
Content-Type: text/plain
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00
Content-Length: 37
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 15:00:13 GMT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try requesting the token with the `read,write,account` scope.  (`account` is required to modify member notifications)